Punctuator does not see changes made to Kafka Streams State Store
We have a Kafka Streams service that uses a KeyValueStore to cache some data. While processing data it puts data into the state store and sometime it deletes data from the state store. That state store is also accessed using an iterator in a Punctuator.
In logging we observe the following updates to the state store from the regular process (not the Punctuator):
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=1]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=2]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=3]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=4]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=5]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=6]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=1, tail=6]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=2, tail=6]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=3, tail=6]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=4, tail=6]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=5, tail=6]
Updating key 'X' to Pointers[head=6, tail=6]
Deleting key 'X'

In the Punctuator we create a KeyValueIterator by calling the method all() on the KeyValueStore, like this:
try (final var iterator = stateStore.all()) {
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {

Then the following information is logged:
Processing key 'X' with value Pointers[head=1, tail=6]

In some way the created iterator contains old data!
While testing we added a call to flush() before opening the iterator, like this:
stateStore.flush();
try (final var iterator = stateStore.all()) {
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {

In this case the data returned by the iterator is correct!
But is this normal behavior?
Edit: the KeyValueStore is a persistent state store backed by RocksDb
Edit: using Kafka Streams 3.5.2 with installation of Kafka 3.1.2
